# How to find median of three points (unsorted) in a generic type of array?

Tags: java, median

I'm trying to find the median of `a[p]`, `a[r]`, and `a[q]` where `q = r+p/2`. My program crashes even though it worked before I created the `median` method, so I'm assuming there's something wrong. Does anyone know what is wrong?

This is what it shows when I run my program:

```
Welcome to DrJava.  Working directory is C:\coding
> run QuickSort
[5, 2, 7, 3, 9, 7, 10, 3, 6, 3, 7, 2, 6, 7, 2, 1]
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at QuickSort.partition(QuickSort.java:39)
    at QuickSort.qSort(QuickSort.java:13)
    at QuickSort.qSort(QuickSort.java:13)
    at QuickSort.qSort(QuickSort.java:13)
    .
    .
    .
    at QuickSort.qSort(QuickSort.java:13)
    at QuickSort.qSort(QuickSort.java:13)
>
```

And the last line keeps repeating.

Complete code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class QuickSort {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Integer[] vals = new Integer[]{5,2,7,3,9,7,10,3,6,3,7,2,6,7,2,1};
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vals));
  qSort(vals,0,vals.length-1);
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vals));
}
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void qSort(T[] a, int p, int r){
  if(p < r){
    int q = partition(a,p,r);
    qSort(a,p,q);
    qSort(a,q+1,r); 
  }
}
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T median(T[] a, int p, int r){
  int q = r+p/2;
  if (a[p].compareTo(a[q]) > 0){
    if (a[q].compareTo(a[r]) > 0){
      return a[q];
    }
    else if (a[p].compareTo(a[r]) > 0){
      return a[r];
    } else{
      return a[p];
    }
  }else{
    if (a[p].compareTo(a[r]) > 0){
      return a[p];
    } else if (a[q].compareTo(a[r]) > 0){
      return a[r];
    } else{
      return a[q];
    }
  }
}
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int partition(T[] a, int p, int r){
  T pivot = median(a,p,r);
  int i = p-1;
  int j = r+1;
  while(true){
    do{
      i++;
    }
    while(i<=r && a[i].compareTo(pivot) < 0);
    do{
      j--;
    }
    while(j>=p && a[j].compareTo(pivot) > 0);
    if(i<j){
      swap(a,i,j);
    }
    else{
      return j;
    }
  }
}
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void swap(T[] a, int i, int j){
  T temp = a[i];
  a[i] = a[j];
  a[j] = temp;
}
}
```

Comment: If it crashes, then you probably received some sort of error message - these messages contain very useful information about where and why the crash occured...

Comment: ive updated it, to show what error message im getting.

Comment: You have a stack-overflow occurring in a different function than the one you've posted here.

Comment: I've shown my complete code... But it's weird, because I only get the stack-overflow if I call median

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with the code you've shown. It crashes in `partition` (probably infinite recursion because you miss a proper stopping condition).

Comment: Also, please use descriptive variable names; `a`, `p`, `q`, and `r` are ambiguous at best.

Comment: @user3251142 You have an infinite recursion - go through it with a debugger and find out why the recursion does not end.

Comment: I've included the full stack trace

Comment: Chances are that your condition (p < r) is never false. So, qsort is being called recursively, but also infinitely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you meant to say:

```
  int q = (r+p)/2;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `qSort` method you call `qSort` if `p < r`. It will only stop recursing when `p >= r`, so it seems that that condition is never met.